# What is $pA$ when $p$ is a prime number and $A$ an abelian group?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, p-groups

Let $A$ be a finite abelian $p$-group. I want to prove that $pA$ is also an abelian finite $p$-group, of order strictly less than the order of $A$.

The problem is that I don't even know what does the notation $pA$ mean. My guess is 
$$pA=\left\{pa\ |\ a\in A\right\}$$
If this is correct, then $pA$ is certainly a finite abelian group, and each element $pa$ of $pA$ has period $p^{r-1}$, if $p^r$ is the period of $a$. But how can I deduce that the order of $pA$ is strictly less than the order of $A$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and if by "period of $A$" you mean *the exponent of* $A$, meaning: the minimal natural $\;n\;$ s.t. $\;na=0\;\;\;\forall\;a\in A\;$ (or $\;a^n=1\;$ , if writing multiplicatively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition for $pA$ is correct (at least it makes a lot of sense, considering what we want to prove)

Here is a short proof for all the problem.

Notice $f:A\rightarrow A$ defined by $f(a)=pa$ is a homomorphism ( we need commutativity for this), the image is $pA$, so it is automatically an abelian subgroup. Now notice that by Cauchy's theorem there is $x$ so that $x$ has order $p$. So $f(x)=e$ and $f$ is not injective, since the group is finite $f$ is not surjective, and so $pA\neq A$ as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is correct.  To show that $pA$ is smaller than $A$, consider the map $f:A\to pA$ given by $f(a)=pa$.  Is this map injective?  Is it surjective?

Comment: in fact it would suffice for $A$ to have order divisible by $p$ wouldn't it ?

Comment: In fact it suffices to take $p$ any integer not coprime with $|A|$ right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.